# Difference of dipole moments of dichloromethane and trichloromethane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polarity

Why is the dipole moment of $\ce{CH2Cl2}$ ($1.60 ~\mathrm{D}$) greater than that of $\ce{CHCl3}$ ($1.08~\mathrm{D}$)?

Based on my knowledge of vectors, I feel it should be the other way around.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just to add some quantification to Ben Norris's answer. Consider each $\ce{C-Cl}$ bond, which has a bond dipole moment of magnitude $A$. The contribution from $\ce{C-H}$ is neglected here to simplify the calculations.

Now consider dichloromethane. The resultant of the two $\ce{C-Cl}$ dipoles will have a magnitude of $$2A\cos\frac\theta2$$
where $\theta\approx109.5^\circ$, the angle between the vectors from the ends of tetrahedron to the centre. This turns out to be $1.154A$.

For tricholoromethane, the three $\ce{C-Cl}$ dipoles will be at an angle $\theta$ such that $\cos\theta=1/3$ with a straight line symmetrically passing through its centre. Thus the resultant in this case will be $$3A\cos\theta$$
which will be $1A$, lesser than in the case of dichloromethane.

To visualise how can you get those angles and cosines, see [this page](http://www.ctralie.com/Teaching/Tetrahedron/).

Answer (score 8):

Since you know about vectors, then the piece you are missing is probably the proper three-dimensional structure of the molecules.

> Trichloromethane (chloroform)

[image: Structure of chloroform]

Notice that the third chlorine atom in trichloromethane is pointing away from the other two. More precisely, the three chlorine atoms are at the bottom three points of a tetrahedron. Thus the $x$ and $y$ components of the individual $\ce{C-Cl}$ bond dipoles cancel, leaving only the $z$ component.

> Dichloromethane

[image: Structure of DCM]

For dichloromethane, the $y$ components fully cancel, but the $x$ components do not.

Comment: But how do you know that the $x$ components in Dicholoromethane sum up to be greater than the $z$ component in Chloroform?