# Hydrogen bond strength of trichloromethane and chloromethane

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, hydrogen-bond

Chloromethane has a larger dipole moment than trichloromethane. Does that mean that the hydrogen bond (C-H...O type) between chloromethane and acetone is stronger than that of trichloromethane and acetone?

Comment: It has nothing to do with dipole moment of molecule, but of the C-H bond. In chloroform it's more polarised, so bond has about 2 kJ per mole. With chloromethane h-bond would be *much* weaker.

Comment: @Mithoron Why chloroform is more polarised than chloromethane? According to [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65965/why-does-chloromethane-have-a-larger-dipole-moment-than-chloroform), chloromethane has a larger dipole moment, does it mean it is more polarised?