# Dipole moment difference between ch2f2 and ch3f

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, bond, halides, hydrocarbons

In CH3F and CH2F2  the net dipole moment increases from 1.82 to 1.97 while in all other halogen substituted carbon atoms the dipole moment decreases. In the case of CH3Cl and CH3F the chlorine substituted methyl group has greater dipole moment due to longer bond length of C-Cl compared to C-F. Then when a compound of formula CH2X2 is formed than dipole moment decreases except in the case of fluorine where it increases.
 Is there any cause to this phenomenon?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do C-F bond has less dipole moment than C-Cl bond?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6780/why-do-c-f-bond-has-less-dipole-moment-than-c-cl-bond)

Comment: Or this https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/65965/50406 ?

Comment: Or this https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/48066/50406?

Comment: Or this https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/8977/50406?

Comment: @Zenix Heheh :D

Comment: @Mithoron ik relatable ;)